# Cheap NMR shift calculations in periodic systems

Tags: electronic-structure, tight-binding, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I am looking for an electronic structure method code (e.g. tight binding  DFTB) that supports cheap calculations of NMR shieldings and has support for periodical systems. I would be grateful for any help!

There exist many codes using GIPAW and GIAO that use expensive DFT calculations.

However, the only papers using DFTB I have found appear not to publish their code or they do not support periodic systems (see e.g. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp9923062)

Comment: I guess the answer will depend heavily on the elements present in your system. For example some (hypothetical) program may support tight-binding-based NMR calculations for H,O,Al,Si only, while another program may support H,C,N,O,F instead.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I should have mentioned that of course.
I am looking rather into organic solids, like H,C,N,O,F

Comment: CENSO can do NMR, currently with implicit solvent. It is based on xTB, and they are implementing periodic boundary conditions, so I would keep an eye on it. https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CENSO_docs/censo_nmr.html

Comment: @B.Kelly But it seems that only the configurational sampling part is done by xTB, and the NMR calculations are done by DFT

Comment: @wzkchem5 that does appear to be the case.

Comment: How fast and how accurate do you need your cheap NMR calculation to be?

Comment: Dear Phil, 
the speed of the method should be in the order of a DFTB calculation.
The method does not need to be, too accurate as I would like to use these calculations as a baseline.
Do you have anything in mind?

Comment: It's possible that Phil didn't see your answer to his question, because you didn't use the "ping" feature. We only get notifications when you use the @ character before the name. I'm pinging @PhilHasnip now in case he didn't see the answer to your question :) **It seems that you're looking for a code that can calculate NMR shifts in periodic systems at DFTB speed but with not much requirement for the accuracy**. Does that help to write an answer Phil?

Comment: Thanks @NikeDattani , I hadn't spotted it. I'll have to think about this, usually NMR calculations are very sensitive to the accuracy of the calculation, but I'll have a look and see if anything crops up.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PhilHasnip!

Comment: Thank you @NikeDattani, I was not aware of the notification settings!

Comment: OK, it appears that there are some efforts to use machine learning to give quick estimates of NMR chemical shifts, e.g. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-06972-x . Initial results from one of my collaborators were not amazing, but not terrible either - perhaps 5-10x the difference from experiment, as compared to DFT (with the usual caveats: DFT structure, T=0 K, classical nuclei etc)

Comment: @PhilHasnip Perhaps you or that collaborator could expand that into an answer? Since the original question says they want "cheap" and then in a comment said "it doesn't need to be too accurate", perhaps that ML-based solution fits the bill for this user :)

Comment: @PhilHasnip Thank you for your Answer! Unfortunately, an ML solution is not suited to my purpose. One of the main reasons is that the way these models are constructed is that they are built on features with a local cutoff and are, therefore, likely to fail in extended pi systems.

Comment: Have you had any luck in finding an answer? Are you still working on this?

Comment: Dear @NikeDattani, No unfortunately no luck. Yes, I am still working on this

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'd just like to check in again since it has been almost 7 months since the last time you wrote a comment here! Is this problem still a sticking-point in your research? How have you moved forward in your research? Please update us :)